# Replacing Github email service with Webhooks

Tags: github, webhooks, github-services

Right now we are using the Github email service so that our team receives notifications whenever changes are made. However, soon Github services will be deprecated. I was wondering if there was any pre existing services that could replicate the behavior that the Github email service produced. This would save us a lot of time and we wouldn't have to run a server just for handling this one webhook.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any turnkey solutions for this? I'm in the same boat yet another service to manage just for git notifications would like to find a replacement for the service.

Comment: @emmdee sorry for the ultra late reply. Unfortunately I didn't find any good services and just ended up writing a little server to handle the github webhooks.

Comment: @Omar Eldar no worries yea I ended up using a free tool called github-webhook-proxy as well. Shame they deprecated this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recently (Nov. 2018) confirmed in "[GitHub Services Brownout Updates and Timeline](https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-11-05-github-services-brownout/)", GitHub services (like [email notification](https://help.github.com/articles/about-email-service-notifications-for-pushes-to-your-repository/)) will disappear in January 2019.

The [original annoucement](https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-10-01-denying-new-github-services/) suggested to [replace them with webhooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/replacing-github-services/#replacing-services-with-webhooks).

> The intention of GitHub Services was to allow third-party developers to submit code for integrating with their services, but this functionality has been superseded by GitHub Apps and webhooks.

In addition, check out [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), still in beta but which have potential.
There are [efforts made to look for a webhook-based alternative](https://github.com/BOINC/boinc/issues/2502) in the meantime. As in for instance [`pyinstaller/pyinstaller` issue 3579](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3579). But no clear answer yet.
**Update Feb. 2020**: this issue is [now closed](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3579#event-3072145287). And GitHub Actions are no longer in beta.